# installing android SDK on removable media

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

what is the pros/cons of installing android SDK for windows on your removable media storage (SD CARDs)?

will there be massive performance hit? I'm in the process of installing it but it takes forever to finish. I'm wondering if it's not going to be usable to have the SDK on my SD CARD and just cancel it rightaway.

Thanks for any response

Comment: I would cancel it right away, if I were you.

Comment: I'm at 86%. at this rate it would probably takes another 30 mins to finish. might as well finish it and see how it goes. i'll be sure to post an update

Comment: Download the SDK in any location in your disk and move to a removable device for use.After that for update it execute android.bat in X:\SDKFOLDER\tools if your SDK Manager.exe won't work, and you make sure that your removable device is attached before execute any IDE or program that requiere use it.